# How to get text from an element with space in javascript

Tags: javascript, element

The HTML code is pretty much like this

```
<div class="place" style="top: 4px;">
    <span class>text</span> 
    <span class>text</span>
    <span class>text</span>
</div>
```

For example with this code

```
let text = document.querySelector("div.place").textContent; //grab all text
```

I get all the text like this: **thisisanexampletext**
Is there a way to get text with spaces after each word?
like this: **this is an example text**

Comment: Show HTML, `textContent` would have worked...

Comment: Can you give us full example using [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) please? Attribute `textContent` returns text content as it is - with whitespaces.

Comment: @decpk not if the text is divided in different childs and there's some css going on.

Comment: can you check if `document.querySelector("div.place").innerText` will do?

Comment: it still gives the same output with no spaces

Answer (score 1):

First you have to collect all the span elements. You then iterate through this collection and can read the text from each element with innerHTML / innerText. You push this into an array and at the end you can make the desired string out of it with the array function join().

```js
let t = document.querySelectorAll("div.place span");

const text = [];
for(let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {   
   text.push(t[i].innerHTML);
}

console.log(text.join(' '));
```

```html
<div class="place" style="top: 4px;">
    <span class>text</span> 
    <span class>text</span>
    <span class>text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible in this way..

```js
let t = document.querySelectorAll("div.place span");

for(let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {   
   t[i].innerHTML += " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="place" style="top: 4px;">
    <span class>text</span> 
    <span class>text</span>
    <span class>text</span>
</div>
```